# how to import vmware's vmdx files to google cloud compute engine?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, google-compute-engine

Does anyone know how to import vmware image like vmdx to google cloud compute engine?
I have check gce component, but these is no import button.

Answer (score 0):

You can [migrate realtime](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/migrating-vms-compute-engine) your virtual machines via CloudEndure tools. You need login with Import button in compute engine page and then you will install an agent on your VM. Migration will starting. When migration is complete, you can create an instance same conf and data on cloud.